# Error while doing principal component analysis

Tags: r, pca

I am working on a [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009) on red wine quality. The dataset has 12 variables and my response variable is `quality`. I am trying to do a principal component analysis (PCA). For that I used the codes as shown below:

```
wine <- read.csv("winequality-red.csv", sep = ";") 
q.pca <- prcomp(wine[, 1:11], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
plot(q.pca, type = "l", main = '')
grid(nx = 10, ny = 14)
title(main = "Principal component weight", sub = NULL, xlab = "components")
box()
```

From the above code I got this output:

[image]
Again moving further, I used the codes mentioned below to plot PCA:

```
devtools::install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
library("ggbiplot")

ggbiplot(
  q.pca, choices = 1:2, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
  groups = q.diag, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, varname.size = 4,
  ellipse.prob = 0.68, circle.prob = 0.69
) +
scale_color_discrete(name = 'Quality (from 3 to 8)') +
theme_bw() +
labs(
  title = "Principal Component Analysis",
  subtitle = "1. Data distribution in the plan of PC1 and PC2\n2. Directions of components in the same plane"
) +
theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'bottom')
```

After this I got an error which mentions:

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Please suggest what went wrong in this code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting the mentioned error. Instead, I'm getting `Error in ggbiplot(q.pca, choices = 1:2, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,  :  object 'q.diag' not found`.

Comment: @Kim, try running the full code from above. q.pca is a variable I have used to store a prcomp function above.

Comment: `q.diag` object is missing, the code runs ok if you comment out the`'groups = q.diag` line. can you provide the object?

Comment: It is clear that the code above is _not_ what produced the graph displayed, because the graph has a typo in the title that is not in the code.